# Elementary Topology Question on Notation

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be a discrete topology on $X$. A question in my text book asks the following if $X\in\tau$ is true, or if $\lbrace{X}\rbrace\in\tau$ is true. It also asks if $\emptyset\subseteq{X}$ or if ${\lbrace\emptyset\rbrace\subseteq{X}}$. I'm not sure what the difference is between having the brackets and not having them.

Comment: Let X={1,2}. Would you say $\{1,2 \}\in \tau$ or $\{\{1,2\}\}\in \tau$?

Comment: @Juanito may have meant, $\{1, 2\} \in \tau$ or $\{\{1, 2\}\} \in \tau$?

Comment: I got it edited ASAP, before I saw your comment.  :) But you need to refresh the page before it shows up.

Comment: The question suggests not knowing the difference between $1$, $\{1\}$ and $\{\{1\}\}$, in which case the Askwer should first get a solid background in set theory.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is the empty set; $\{\emptyset\}$ is the set containing the empty set.

Comment: Ah, I see thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly brackets indicate a set containing whatever is inside them. Thus $\{1\}$ is referring to the set which contains $1$ as its only element. Now $X$ and $\emptyset$ are already sets by definition. So $\{X\}$ would be the set containing as its only element $X$, whereas $X$ itself is the set containing possibly infinite elements, e.g $\mathbb R$. Similarly $\emptyset$ is the set containing no elements, whereas $\{\emptyset\}$ is the set containing one element, namely $\emptyset$.

A topology $\tau$ on $X$ is a collection of subsets of your base set $X$ satisfying certain properties. Now $X\subset X$ and $\emptyset\subset X$, because every element in $X$ is in $X$, and as $\emptyset$ has no elements it is vacuously true that every element in the empty set is in $X$, but, unless you have a very weird set, $\{\emptyset\}\not\subset X$, as the empty set is not an *element* of your set.

Answer (score 1):

**Example.** The discrete topology on $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$ would be the power set

$$
{\cal P}(X) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}
$$

Using that example as a model, can you answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

$\emptyset \subseteq X$ here $\emptyset$ is the empty set which is a subset of any set $X$. However, if we write $\{\emptyset\}$ this is a set that contains the element $\emptyset$.